# SSRS design is not the same with the other browser

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need your help. I just notice that, the design of the SSRS report is not the same with the other browser.

In my IE. You need to scroll the report and it is too small. See image below.
[image: In my IE. You need to scroll the report and it is too small. See image below.]

In my CHROME. It is full screen.

[image: In my CHROME. It is full screen.]

I don't know what's the problem. Please help. I've already adjust the width of the report. And no luck. It's the same.

Comment: are u using ReportViewer (if so - what version) or Report manager directly? Also what version of IE?

Comment: Hi I'm using ReportViewer 2008 from SQL server 2008 R2 and for the IE I'm using IE10.

Comment: Then it could be compatibility issue I believe. Only most recent versions began to support IE9, not to mention IE10. Try running it in compatibility mode,